# What more security measurements I can apply to my app?

Tags: android, security, google-cloud-functions

I have been struggling with my app security for these past months. My app consists of playing some simple games and these past months, a lot of users have been trying to break the app security and cheat their points. I know that cheating in a game will be a constant fight, and I have been doing my best to secure my app. As for now, I have implemented the following:

- Using the **CommonUtils.isRooted(this)** from Crashlytics to see if the user has a rooted device;
- Using **Firebase Call functions** with **FirebaseAppCheck** to make only secure devices and make the requests only from the app;
- In the server-side function, I am implementing a basic function to verify if the points are valid;
- Added obfuscation with the **Proguard-rules**;
- **UPDATE**: Added Firebase Auth sign in;

I was pretty confident that the Firebase Call functions working with a server-side function to verify the points the user made each match, would be enough for now. But one user did manage to break this and is able to add multiple games with the maximum points possible each second.

I am not sure how he did this. I suspect that maybe he injected some code, and was able to compile the app with his code, running the Firebase Call Function with the params he wants to, but I have no clue on how to prevent this.

That's why I am creating this question. Are there any more security measurements that I can apply? I am getting desperate with the app security and don't know what to do more.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the Firebase Authentication System would secure it further, and perhaps to the maximum extent. It offers a lot of sign-in options to users, so I think it'd be a good choice. Or you could use a custom sign-in flow with oAtuh Clients

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. But the only way to sign in in my app, is through Firebase Auth. In my case, using Google sign in provider. Even with that, someone managed to break security.

Comment: Then you must check the rules of your realtime database. That's what developers exploit

Comment: Restricted access can help prevent that.

Comment: All my Firestore rules are read-only. All the write logic is made by a Firebase Call Function, that checks if the requester has a valid Auth token and fails if the token is not valid.